# How do I make the YouTube video stop playing when the outside of the video is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, youtube

I have a YouTube video modal appear when an image is clicked within the banner. The YouTube video is set to auto play, but how do I make the YouTube video stop playing when the outside of the video is clicked?

HTML Codes

```
<div class="banner-image">
  <div class="banner-image-container">
    <div class="image"><a href="#media-popup" data-media="//www.youtube.com/embed/qfGggAGITwg?rel=0&autoplay=1"><img src="/files/theme/images/hover.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="popup" id="media-popup">
      <div class="video-container">
        <div class='embed-container'>
          <iframe id="player" frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Codes

```
.banner-image {
    height:100%;
}

.popup {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding-top:100px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition:.3s ease;
}

.show-popup .popup {
    opacity:1;
    visibility: visible;    
}
```

jQuery Codes

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("[data-media]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var videoUrl = $this.attr("data-media");
    var popup = $this.attr("href");
    var $popupIframe = $(popup).find("iframe");

    $popupIframe.attr("src", videoUrl);

    $this.closest(".banner-image").addClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(".banner-image").removeClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup > iframe").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/9skjg5Lg/

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("[data-media]").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      var videoUrl = $this.attr("data-media");
      var popup = $this.attr("href");
      var $popupIframe = $(popup).find("iframe");

      $popupIframe.attr("src", videoUrl);

      $this.closest(".banner-image").addClass("show-popup");
  });

  $(".popup").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      var src = $(this).find('iframe').attr('src').replace('autoplay=1', 'autoplay=0');
      $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', src);
      //$(".banner-image").removeClass("show-popup");
  });

  $(".popup > iframe").on("click", function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```css
.banner-image {
    height:100%;
}

.popup {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding-top:100px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition:.3s ease;
}

.show-popup .popup {
    opacity:1;
    visibility: visible;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-image">
  <div class="banner-image-container">
    <div class="image"><a href="#media-popup" data-media="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qfGggAGITwg?rel=0&autoplay=1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></a></div>
    <div class="popup" id="media-popup">
      <div class="video-container">
        <div class='embed-container'>
          <iframe id="player" frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Replace the `autoplay=1` with `autoplay=0` to stop the video. I've attached the same in `.popup` click event.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Welcome buddy :)